# Vaadin - JPAContainer filter Join in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, vaadin, jpacontainer

I have a ManyToMany relationship between User and Context class with an extra-column in the intermediate table.

### Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users {
    private Long user_id;
    private Long niu;
    private String nom;
    private String mail;
    private Set<UserContext> userContexts  = new HashSet<UserContext>(0);
```

### Context.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTEXT")
public class Context {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Area area;
    private String code;
    private Set<UserContext> userContexts = new HashSet<UserContext>(0);
```

### UserContext.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_CTX")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.context",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CTXT_ID")) })
public class UserContext implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserContextID pk = new UserContextID();
    private String admin;
```

### UserContextID.java

```
@Embeddable
public class UserContextID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9120607274421816301L;
    private Users user;
    private Context context;
```

I have a table that is filled using a JPAContainer,

```
private JPAContainer<Users> persons =
    JPAContainerFactory.make(Users.class, PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
```

actually it shows all the User (without filter by Context), that I want is filter by a concrete context id using this ManyToMany relationship, any idea? I have tried to use JoinFilters but I couldn't get it, help me please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filter, selecting the right sub-property with dot notation like, for example

```
entityContainer.addContainerFilter(new Like("listOfAnotherEntity.type", "TYPE1"));
```